# System bug in AVPlayer causes player's system wide to stop playing

Tags: ios, avfoundation

Have little hope that anyone's encountered this, but there seems to be a system wide bug with AVPlayer. I've tested with my app along with other apps, including Pandora.

Namely, and randomly, if you successfully open the app and begin playing, then put the app in the background, perform a variety of random actions, such as playing media in other apps, making a phone call, etc, and try to come back to the app, the AVPlayer's don't play.

I've replicated this many times, though inconsistently, with Pandora and the app that I'm working on.

I've logged my code and have not found any errors in playback. It just doesn't play.

Has anyone else experienced this strange issue? I have spent countless days on it and am now desperate.

Comment: I've not seen it, but you should [file a bug](http://bugreporter.apple.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the AVFoundation media server is crashing and resetting, causing this problem.

The solution:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1749/_index.html